# Is the anime adaptation of Tokyo Ghoul:re faithful to the manga?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I've seen the first 2 episodes of *Tokyo Ghoul:re* and got confused when Kaneki meets Touka. I dropped the manga a while ago though, so I might be wrong thinking that they have not met this early.

Is the anime following the manga closely, or is it as far off as the *Root A* was?

Answer (score 1):

Having watched all the anime episodes so far, except maybe the one released today, and all the Re manga chapters, they do match up very closely. There might be some minor events missing, but it seems like everything is being included.

Thus, of the 3 anime seasons of Tokyo Ghoul, it seems Re is the most faithful to the manga. Even season 1 mixed up the order and changed some events, but I have yet to see any such thing in Re.

Comment: Thanks for that :). Shouldn't they just release more episodes / seasons instead of rushing? ;). Wishful thinking

Answer (score 0):

**To be true, it's not as bad as Root A was.**

That abomination was literally the worst thing that could happen to Tokyo Ghoul, in my opinion. But yeah, they are rushing things up a little, and that's expected when you are talking about a series that's already has more than 170 chapters as base material.
Spoilers ahead..

> *Around 8 episodes of :Re are out as of now, and Sasaki has already met a recovered Tsukiyama. I think that was the point where he started getting his memories back little by little, though they haven't showed it in the anime till now. The same event happened much later considering the manga chapters.*

This season of :re is only going to have 12 episodes, check [here on MAL](https://myanimelist.net/anime/36511/Tokyo_Ghoul_re). So I think it has been okay till now. I like the progress anyway. The main issue is, they are supposed to come out with the *next 12 episodes* by the end of this year, read [here](https://www.inquisitr.com/4854408/tokyo-ghoul-re-season-2-release-date-tokyo-ghoul-season-4-sui-ishida-manga/). If they screw that up, it will spoil the whole of re, as Root A did with Tokyo Ghoul.

I just hope they don't screw it up anymore _/\_

Answer (score 0):

The Tokyo Ghoul re anime only seemed to reorder events a little during the first episode, which skipped a lot of exposition about how the world worked and RC cells. Little details are skipped, and character backstory for the Quinx Squad is limited compared to the manga.

As already mentioned above, [Tokyo Ghoul Season 4](https://www.monstersandcritics.com/anime/tokyo-ghoul-season-4-release-date-confirmed-for-2018-tokyo-ghoul-re-season-2-anime-leaves-room-for-tokyo-ghoul-season-5-based-on-mangas-ending/) is coming out soon. However, it's unknown if it's just another 12 episodes. It could potentially be two cours and finish off the manga.